# Does wp_remote_post() require curl?

Tags: curl, wp-remote-post

Does the following code require curl?

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, [ 'body' => json_encode( $data ) ] );
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the code without curl?

Comment: @czerspalace I don't have access to `php.ini` to disable curl.

Comment: Check your error logs to find out.